# Send email to users who finished submitting a product review in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, email-notifications

I am using the following code which works fine.

```php
function send_comment_email_notification( $comment_ID, $commentdata ) {
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
    $postid = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    $master_email = 'email@gmail.com';
    var_dump($commentdata);
    if( isset( $master_email ) && is_email( $master_email ) ) {
        $message = 'New comment on <a href="' . get_permalink( $postid ) . '">' .  get_the_title( $postid ) . '</a>';
        add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', create_function( '', 'return "text/html";' ) );
        wp_mail( $master_email, 'New Comment', $message );
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'send_comment_email_notification', 11, 2 );
```

However, I would like to send an email to the user who just reviewed on a product page so I can offer them a coupon and a thank you for giving a review.

The problem is the `$master_email` variable, that is "hard coded". I need to capture the email entered by the user after he/she submitted the product review

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the  email entered by the user after he/she submitted the product review, you can use `$commentdata['comment_author_email']`

So you get:

```php
function action_comment_post( $comment_ID, $comment_approved, $commentdata ) {  
    // Isset
    if ( isset ( $commentdata['comment_author_email'] ) ) {
        // Get author email
        $author_email = $commentdata['comment_author_email'];

        if ( is_email( $author_email ) ) {
            // Post ID
            $post_id = $commentdata['comment_post_ID'];
            
            // Send e-mail
            $to = $author_email;
            $subject = 'The subject';
            $body = sprintf( __(' Thank you for giving a review on %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '">' .  get_the_title( $post_id ) . '</a>' );
            $headers = array( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
            
            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
        }
    } 
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'action_comment_post', 10, 3 );
```